# value iteration update rule in MDP

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix

Well, I'm new to MDP and I have a basic question about the formulation of the transition matrix (T).
The way I would think about it when constructing T is an SxS matrix when S is the number of states.
where each Tij is the probability of moving from state i to state j.
I've been tasked with an exercise that puts another layer in the T matrix:
The new layer is that there is a probability of success when moving from i to j, I quote from the exercise:
"An agent moves in a 1D grid of 5 blocks, at any given grid location the agent can choose to either stay at the location or move to an adjacent grid location,with a probability of success in each case of 0.5"
then it continues:
"If the agent chooses to move (either left or right) at any of the inner grid locations, such an action is successful with probability 1/3 and with probability 2/3 it fails to move".
and then adds:
"if the agent chooses to move left at the leftmost (or right to the rightmost) grid location the last probabilities are 0.5."
In the model answer, the T matrix was given by a 5x3x5.
it added the probability of movement success and I can't see the intuition behind this formulation.
I added an image of the T matrix it suggested highlighting the middle rows in each row block together would form what I would be thinking of when I tried to build it.
can somebody demystify me the intuition behind it?
[Solution of the transition matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1OWe.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Saying the "probability of success" is $p$ is the not a new layer, it merely specifies that $T_{ii}=p$, i.e., you stay in state $i$ with probability $p$.

Comment: Taking a guess, I'd say if you imagine a transition matrix as an $S\times S$ matrix, you're probably thinking about Markov chains. The new layer that MDPs add is actions where now in each state you have a set of actions available, each with its own transition probabilities. The now $S\times A\times S$ matrix specifies the probability of transitioning from state $i$ to state $j$ when action $a$ is chosen in state $i$. Lastly, I'm not sure how this connects to the title of your question...